# How to deal with asynchronous functions without promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I started doing web-app development with angularJS which comes with a promise library but now I have to work on another project without one. How would I do this without having to import a promise library.

I've removed some of the irrelevant things but basically I need to get a file url from the backend, create an element based on this url, and then return the element. The thing is once I go inside the async function, I don't know how to get back out to return the created element.

```
        var userLogoAWS = null;
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/apps/admin/file",
               {
                category: category,
                filename: "logo.png"
               },
               function(data){
                userLogoAWS = data;
               });

        img.src   = userLogoAWS;

        //---- Create and Combine elements ----
        var element = anchor.appendChild(img);

        return element;
```

Comment: you are using jquery, so you _have_ a promise library: the `Deferred` object is your freind

Comment: Hmm...didn't know that. I read somewhere about a "q" library so I thought people were using that. I'm going to check out jQuery's. BTW, is there no way to deal with this without promises?

Comment: `return $.get("http://...",{}).then(function(result){ var img = new Image(); img.src = result; anchor.appendChild(img);return img});` Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of a simple callback pattern in this case. there are a lot of ways to do this but the key thing is passing a function that handles the success of the ajax call as an argument to the function that makes the ajax call.

```
function getLogo(createElement){
   $.get("http://localhost:8080/apps/admin/file",
               {
                category: category,
                filename: "logo.png"
               },
               function(data){
                 createElement(data)
               });
}

function createElement(logo){
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = logo;
   var element = anchor.appendChild(img);
   return element; //or assign element to a global variable
}

var element = getLogo(createElement);
```

if this does not work, JQuery has a promise library and it seems you are using jquery, so why not take advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the created element. period. Fortunately for you though, you're using jQuery which comes with it's own deferred/promise system so you can continue with the promise setup you're used to.

```
function doSomething() {
    return $.get("http://localhost:8080/apps/admin/file", {
        category: category,
        filename: "logo.png"
    });
}
doSomething().done(function(data){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    //---- Create and Combine elements ----
    var element = anchor/*where is anchor defined?*/.appendChild(img);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you are using jquery, so you *have* a promise library: the [`Deferred` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) is your friend. See in particular the docs on the [`.promise` method](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Comment: I don't understand how this is an attempt to answer the question at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum quote OP: 'I started doing web-app development with angularJS which comes with a promise library but now I have to work on another project without one. How would I do this without having to import a promise library.'. Which basically states, that he would know how to proceed if he had a promise library at his disposal. His code sample includes a jquery method call. jquery comes with a promise object. hence my answer that put the strings together. for details, read kevinb's answer.